# Why does trying to set the value of my NSProgressIndicator crash my application?

Tags: swift, null, option-type, nsprogressindicator

When trying to set the progress from a URLSessionDownloadTask, I get a `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error. What I'm trying to accomplish is have a separate class, a `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`, handle the download and update the necessary UI elements, in this case, an `NSProgressIndicator`. Here's my code:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
@IBOutlet var button: NSButton!
@IBOutlet var progind: NSProgressIndicator!


@IBAction func update(_ sender:AnyObject){
    button.isEnabled = false
    updater().downloadupdate(arg1: "first argument")
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    progind.doubleValue = 50.0 //me trying to test if the progress indicator even works
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
}
func updateDownload(done: Double, expect: Double){
    print(done)
    print(expect)
    progind.maxValue = expect //this line crashes from the unexpected nil error
    progind.doubleValue = done //so does this one, if I delete the one above
}
}
```

updater.swift

```
import Foundation

class updater: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {



func downloadupdate(arg1: String){
    print(arg1)
    let requestURL: URL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
    let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let downloads = session.downloadTask(with: urlRequest)

    print("starting download...")
    downloads.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){
    print("download finished!")
    print(location)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    let expectDouble = Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    let doneDouble = Double(totalBytesWritten)
    AppDelegate().updateDownload(done: doneDouble, expect: expectDouble)
}
}
```

I have tried replacing

```
 AppDelegate().updateDownload(done: doneDouble, expect: expectDouble)
```

with

```
 AppDelegate().progind.maxValue = expect 
 AppDelegate().progind.doubleValue = done
```

and had the same results.

I actually think I know what is causing this. My research has led me to believe that I'm actually declaring a NEW instance of `AppDelegate`, in which `progind` doesn't even exist! So how can I properly set the value of `progind`, while keeping as much of the process as possible in updater.swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, when you type `AppDelegate()`, you are creating a new object.  Since it's new, it doesn't have any of the outlets initialized for it the way one does when it comes from a storyboard or xib.

You need to get the shared singleton that represents your application (see `NSApplication` docs), ask it for its delegate, cast that to an `AppDelegate`, and set the property there.

Sample code (Swift 2.2):

```
if let delegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
    delegate.progind.maxValue = expected
} else {
    print("Unexpected delegate type: \(NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Under what circumstances would the shared delegate type be incorrect?

Comment: None that I can think off except a typing mistake, but I'd rather have the test than crash if something happens that I haven't considered.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! My `updater` file does not seem to be able to ask for the delegate, so I'm assuming I get that with `AppDelegate`. However I do not seem to be able to pass that *correctly* to `updater`. I tried passing it as the arg1 parameter in `AppDelegate`, and `updater` seems to be able to read it *only* until the download starts. When `didFinishDownloadingTo` and `didWriteData` are called, `delegate` now has a `nil` value. I tried declaring `delegate` in several places and they all end up `nil` by the time I need them. Any thoughts? Or is this a question to ask in a new post?

Comment: This "does not seem to be able to ask for the delegate" needs explanation.  What error do you get?  (What if you import Cocoa instead of Foundation?)

Comment: For instance, when I press a button in my app, it tells the main `AppDelegate` to send its shared singleton as an argument `arg1`. The function is `updater().downloadupdate(arg1: delegate)`. In `downloadUpdate`, `arg1.progind.doubleValue = 75.0` is successful. `updater` is a `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`, so in it I have declared `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)`. In the body of `didFinishDownloadingTo`, XCode tells me the `arg1` is an unresolved identifier. So it appears that `arg1` is not passed from

Comment: `downloadupdate` to `didFinishDownloadingTo`. How do I pass that arg1 so that it goes through to `didFinishDownloadingTo`?

Comment: Importing cocoa did not fix the problem.

Comment: What **is** the problem if you use `NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` inside `updater`?  (There's no advantage to passing the delegate around since it should always be available from the `sharedApplication`.)

Comment: I got it! Importing cocoa actually *did* fix it. When I used foundation, `NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` returned `unresolved identifier` error. Importing Cocoa allowed me to use `NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` in `updater`. Thank you so much for your help, and for helping me to better understand how swift works!